# Replace IF(AND)) function with Array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am using IF(AND) function in a worksheet, as the worksheet has 10000+ rows i have to drag this formula to the bottom, so the sheet is little slow and if someone accidentally deletes the formula in a cell it would be a problem.

So putting array formula may solve these issues.

here is the worksheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VsLKHSZsTMeBctnINnsixKISgNkTHDV-dkO4ORsDjgI/edit#gid=1975041699

Comment: Please **do NOT use 2 questions in one post**. Edit your question, delete the second part and make it a **NEW question**. What you do confuses users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `arrayformula` question please use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IFS(D3:D="yes",5,D3:D="no",0)))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145)